# Actionscript 3 Vector Number does not extend Vector *

Tags: actionscript-3, vector, numbers, standards

I am currently being confused by the `Vector` class.
I wrote a beautiful `XML` to TypedClass parser. Works beautifully and without fault. **UNTIL** a co-worker noticed we got a Conversion Error for `Vector.<Number> to Vector.<*>`.

Every `Vector` I've ever tested all extend `Vector.<*>`.

`Vector.<Sprite>`, `Vector.<String>`, `Vector.<Point>`, `Vector.<Boolean>`, `Vector.<TextField>`, `Vector.<CustomObject>`, etc etc etc. ALL of them.

```
<type name="__AS3__.vec::Vector.<String>" base="__AS3__.vec::Vector.<*>" isDynamic="true" isFinal="false" isStatic="false">
  <extendsClass type="__AS3__.vec::Vector.<*>"/>
  <extendsClass type="Object"/>
  <accessor name="length" access="readwrite" type="uint" declaredBy="__AS3__.vec::Vector.<*>"/>
  <accessor name="fixed" access="readwrite" type="Boolean" declaredBy="__AS3__.vec::Vector.<*>"/>
</type>
```

But then when I use describeType on `Vector.<Number>`, `Vector.<uint>` and `Vector.<int>`.

```
<type name="__AS3__.vec::Vector.<Number>" base="Object" isDynamic="true" isFinal="true" isStatic="false">
  <extendsClass type="Object"/>
  <constructor>
    <parameter index="1" type="uint" optional="true"/>
    <parameter index="2" type="Boolean" optional="true"/>
  </constructor>
  <accessor name="length" access="readwrite" type="uint" declaredBy="__AS3__.vec::Vector.<Number>"/>
  <accessor name="fixed" access="readwrite" type="Boolean" declaredBy="__AS3__.vec::Vector.<Number>"/>
</type>
```

Now I have accounted for these 3 vectors individually as even uint and int does not extend `Vector.<Number>` as I would have expected.
And my parsing function works for all types correctly again. But my confusion comes as to WHY this is the case, and why I couldn't find any documentation on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question on the Kirupa forums a few months back, but I cannot for the life of me find the thread.

If I remember this correctly, the `Vector.<Number>`, `Vector.<int>`, and `Vector.<uint>` (but not `Boolean` or `String`, oddly enough) classes are made to be *as fast as possible*, so they are written and treated as separate classes by the Flash Player.

As you have noticed, all other Vector classes extend `Vector.<*>` and type checking is done a bit differently (which is why Vectors are faster with int, uint, and Number, but Arrays are slightly faster for all other classes)

---

Anyway, that was the **WHY**. As for how to get around this issue, I'm afraid you are going to have to pass your vector as *untyped* to the function you want to use it in:

```
public function addItem(vector:*, item:*)
    { vector.push(item); }
```

Comment: Interesting. I thought that this was due to primitive types, but it looks as though [Strings and Booleans fall under that category as well.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9c.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f88)

Comment: Well, technically my function takes a class and then tests if that class is of type `Vector`. Which of course a Vector of Number and anything else actually falls under but when I tried to assign a new instance of the class I passed in it to a variable I had set up for `Vector.<*>` I had major fail. As I said in the question, I have since accounted for this. We rarely use `Vector.<Number>`, just annoying I have to account for them separately. It was nice and neat before. :-(